# Problema con FullCalendar y timeZone

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, timezone

Tengo un calendario creado con `fullCalendar`, el cual se puede completar mediante `drags&drops`, y un `botón Guardar` que va a recoger todos los eventos del calendario para posteriormente, guardarlos en un `json` y mandarlo a una `db`.

**La cosa es que cuando saco por consola de `js` cada uno de los eventos del calendario, me los muestra con -3 horas de diferencia.** Estimo que podría solucionarlo con lograr cambiar la hora de `GMT-3` a `GMT0`, pero no sé como hacerlo.

> Este es el código del calendario

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'America/New_York',
    plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid'],
    defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
    defaultDate: hoy,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    businessHours: [ // specify an array instead
        {
            daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
            startTime: '09:00', // 8am
            endTime: '21:00' // 6pm
        }
    ],
    minTime: "09:00",
    maxTime: "21:00",
    events: [{
        title: 'Agustin Guerra',
        start: '2020-02-27T10:30:00',
        end: '2020-02-27T11:30:00',
    }],

    editable: true,
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
    drop: function(info) {

        info.draggedEl.parentNode.removeChild(info.draggedEl);

    }
});

calendar.render();
```

Al apretar un botón, yo quiero guardar todos los eventos que hay en el calendario en una base de datos. Para eso tengo la siguiente función

```
$(document).on("click", "button.guardarCalendario", function() {
    var eventos = calendar.getEvents();
    console.log(eventos);

    eventos.forEach(e => {

        console.log(e._instance["range"]["start"])
        console.log(e._instance["range"]["end"])
        console.log(e._def["title"])
    });
})
```

> Como pueden ver, mi calendario solo tiene un evento estático de 10.30 a 11.30. Pero la función anterior, si bien "funciona", me retorna lo siguiente:

```
Thu Feb 27 2020 07:30:00 GMT-0300 (hora estándar de Argentina)
turnos.js:160 Thu Feb 27 2020 08:30:00 GMT-0300 (hora estándar de Argentina)
turnos.js:161 Agustin Guerra
```

> Me muestra las horas con -3 de diferencia. Quisiera saber si puedo cambiar la zona horaria en alguna parte del `fullCalendar` para evitar modificar las horas cada vez que quiero visualizarlas.

Intenté con `timeZone: 'America/New_York'` y con `timeZone: 'local'` y siempre obtengo el mismo resultado.

Comment: La solucion al problema la encontre en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46847166/full-calendar-event-time-adding-an-hour-on-chrome-and-safari-browser y funcionó de maravillas.